# Datepicker problem using tabs (Tabwidget)

Tags: android, datepicker, tabwidget

The datepicker runs without problem. But if the datepicker is under tabwidget, it failed. Anyone has experience on that ??? and how to solve it ??

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    layout = new LinearLayout(this);  
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        date = new Button(this);

        date.setText("Choose Date");
        layout.addView(date,
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        date.setOnClickListener(this);
        incomehelper = new FinanceHelper(this);
        chosenDate = incomehelper.getToday();
        setContentView(layout);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
      showDialog(DATE_ID);
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int calyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int calmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int calday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        switch (id) 
        {
            case DATE_ID:
               return new DatePickerDialog(this,  mDateSetListener,  calyear, calmonth, calday);
        }
            return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() 
    {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
        {
           chosenDate = incomehelper.getSelectedDate(dayOfMonth,monthOfYear,year);
           Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Date Selected is ="+chosenDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: If I don't use Tabwidget to include datepicker, the dialog can be shown without problem. But when I added the datepicker using Tabwidget approch, when I click "choose date" button, the program crash. I also created a test activity only contains button, when I click button, it allows me to choose date. For test activity, I don't use any tabwidget. The problem of tabwidget is that I only can include some textview using XML approach. In XML file, I cannot define which tab contains which UI components. So I need to create those UI components on the fly using java code. But it causes some problem.

Comment: Actually I have two activities. On the main activity, I create a new instance of layout defined in second activity. Then all the layouts and items event are defined in second activity. Also datepicker is in second activity. I tried to replace showDialog(DATE_ID) with activity.showDialog(DATE_ID), but it shows nothing. activity is class variable of constructor in second activity. I create the layout on the fly and populate layout into two tabs, first tab contains textview, editview, datepicker. second tab contains only textview. I suspect that there is problem in activity but don't know how...